# How do I use middle mouse button scrolling/autoscrolling on Microsoft Edge for Linux (Beta)?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mouse, scrolling, microsoft-edge

I often use a scroll function that is referred to by some browsers as "autoscrolling" where the user presses the middle mouse button, moves the cursor in any direction, and the view moves in that direction. However, the Microsoft Edge for Linux Beta v95.0.1020.30-1 does not seem to have this feature by default. Is there a way to activate or implement this feature in MS Edge v95.0.1020.30-1? I am currently using Ubuntu 21.10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found one solution that works for most pages: the [Autoscroll Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/autoscroll/occjjkgifpmdgodlplnacmkejpdionan)